# Inversion and correlation of Binomial random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, correlation, independence

Assume $A$ is $Bin(1, 1/2)$ and $B$ is $Bin(1, 1/4)$, where $X=A+B$ and $Y= AB$ and I am interested in knowing how to find their inversion so that I could use the good old transformation theorem
$$f_{XY} (\cdot, \cdot ) |\mathbf{J}|$$
where $\mathbf{J}$ is the usual jacobian to find their joint distribution. But the inversion seems a difficult task; it seems $A$ and $B$ cannot be made the subject of $X=A+B$ and $Y= AB,$ for example $A = X-B$ then $Y = (X-B)B$, $B$ is a square making it hard. Plugging $A = Y/B$ into $X = (Y/B) + B$, again a quadratic.

Granted that the inversion is possible so that the joint distribution can be found, what is the smarter way for computing the correlation between $X$ and $Y$? Generally, we need to find the Cov$(X,Y)$ and divide by their product of the standard deviations (square root of variances). This approach is always tedious and time consuming.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to find.  For example, if you know $X=1$ and $Y=0$ then you can say either $A=0$ and $B=1$ or $A=1$ and $B=0$ but you cannot determine which.  Or if you know $\mathbb P(Y=1) = k$ with $0 \le k \le \frac14$ then you can say the covariance of $A$ and $B$ is $k-\frac18$ and their correlation is $\sqrt{\frac83}(k-\frac18)$.  The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ has $\mathbb P(X=2,Y=1) = k$, $\mathbb P(X=1,Y=0) = \frac34-2k$, and $\mathbb P(X=0,Y=0) = \frac14+k$.

Comment: Your question says $Y=AB$ while your comment says $Y=A-B$.  This makes a big difference as to whether you can go from $X$ and $Y$ back to $A$ and $B$

Comment: For example $A$ and $B$ are independent $N(0,1)$. Find the joint-distribution of $X=A+B$ and $Y = A-B.$ Here, the *INVERSION* is $A=(X+Y)/2$ and $B=(X-Y)/2$ which implies $J=-1/2.$
 By the transformation theorem, 
 
$$f_{X,Y} (x,y)= f_{(A,B)} \left( \frac{(x+y)}{2} + \frac{(x-v)}{2}\right)|\mathbf{J}|
 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \cdot 2 }} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \cdot 2 }} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{y^2}{2}} $$

Comment: The example from my comment is when the inversion is easy. But my posted question's inversion seems a little bit challenging.

Comment: Another thing I do not understand is that I thought the use of the Jacobian in a change of variables  was related to the density, but here you have discrete distributions

Comment: Well catch. For the discrete case, just like my question, how do I proceed?

Comment: My first comment gave the joint distribution for $X$ and $Y$.  The joint distribution for $(A,B)$ is $P(A=1,B=1)=k$, $P(A=1,B=0)=\frac14-k$, $P(A=0,B=1)=\frac12-k$, $P(A=0,B=0)=\frac14+k$. You can say $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $k=\frac18$.

Comment: Are the values for $A$ and $B$ the support for the distribution $\{0,1\}?$ And when I computed say $P(A=1, B=0)$, I had $1/8,$ maybe I'm missing something. Can you show explicitly how for instance $P(A=1, B=0) = \frac14-k?$ The iff statement can also be expanded for me to clearly understand. Thanks!

Comment: To get $P(A=1, B=0)=\frac18$ you probably assumed $A$ and $B$ are independent, which in my comment means $k=\frac18$.    If $k=P(Y=1)=P(A=1,B=1)$ then $P(A=1, B=0)=P(A=1)-P(A=1,B=1)=\frac14-k$ and using $k=\frac18$ makes $\frac14-k=\frac18$.

Comment: In less time than it takes to post this question you could tabulate the values and probabilities of all four possible combinations of $(A,B)$ and then adjoin two more columns for their sum and product, from which you can read off the entire joint distribution of $(A+B,AB).$  The most difficult calculation (by far) in this process is to work out the probabilities by multiplication :-).  Once you have seen how easy and convenient tabulation is for problems with small discrete random variables, you will resort to this technique often, to great effect.

Comment: @holala I don't want to seem obdurate, but could you give me a clearer characterization of what you mean by "such questions"?

Comment: @whuber "such" should be replaced with "similar". I mean a good textbook that treat in detail similar questions posted by the OP.

Comment: @holala I'm still at a loss to know what you are asking for, because you haven't explained the sense of "similar."  About transforming random variables?  About bivariate variables?  About discrete distributions?  About the confusion between pdfs and pmfs?  About computing correlation?

Comment: @holala It sounds like you need a large, comprehensive textbook, along the lines of [Kendall & Stuart.](https://www.amazon.com/Kendalls-Advanced-Theory-Statistics-Distribution/dp/0195205618)

Answer (score 2):

This approach (inverting the transformation, finding the Jacobian, etc.) is applicable when $A$ and $B$ are jointly continuous random variables, and $f_{A,B}$ is their joint density function. In this problem they are discrete case, so we would do something like

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \sum_{(a,b)\, s.t. \\ x=a+b,\\ y=ab} f_{A,B}(a,b)  $$

where the sum is over all pairs of values $(a,b)$ that give you the desired $(x,y)$. For example, if $X=1$ and $Y=0$ you need to take $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $(a,b)=(1,0)$.

Also, you talk about computing the correlation between $A$ and $B$, but in your setup these appear to be independent. Do you mean the correlation between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes. $Corr(X,Y).$ That was a typo.

Comment: You don't need to find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ to work this out.

We have $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathrm{Cov}(A+B, AB) = \mathrm{Cov}(A, AB) + \mathrm{Cov}(B, AB)$. Notice that $\mathrm{Cov}(A, AB)=\mathbb{E}(A^2 B)-\mathbb{E}(A)\mathbb{E}(AB) = (\mathbb{E}(A^2)-\mathbb{E}(A)^2)\mathbb{E}(B)=Var(A)\mathbb{E}(B)$, and similarly for the other term.

Comment: Following your example, for $X=1$ and $Y=0$, $(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $(a,b) = (1,0)$ $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \sum_{(a,b)\, s.t. \\ x=a+b,\\ y=ab} f_{A,B}(a,b) = \sum f_{A,B}(0,1) + f_{A,B}(1,0) = 2{2 \choose 1} \left(  \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(  \frac{1}{2}\right) +2{2 \choose 0} \left(  \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(  \frac{1}{2}\right) >1 $$ What is wrong with my expansion of the sum? Where the first binomial term is for when $X=1$ and the second binomial term is for when $Y=0.$

Comment: Remember that $A \sim \mathrm{Bin}(1,1/2)$ and $B\sim \mathrm{Bin}(1,1/4)$, so

$$f_{A,B}(0,1)=\Pr(A=0) \Pr(B=1) = \frac12 \,\frac14 = \frac18 $$ and similarly for the other term.